# Что-то идёт не так jQuery

Tags: jquery

Хочу, чтобы при клике на картинку, она вставала вместо главной картинки big img (соответственно её src, менялось на href нажатой картинки), return false стоит для того, чтобы ссылка не открывалась, а просто картинки менялись меж собой. По итогу происходит открытие ссылки.  Не понимаю что не так :(

```
$('#small a').click(function(eventObject) {
    $('#big img').hide().attr('src',$(this).attr('href'));
    $('#big img').load(function() {
       $(this).fadeIn(2000); 
    });
    return false; // пробовал eventObject.preventDefault(); - тоже самое 
});
```

Comment: Хорошо бы увидеть пример разметки, которую вы используете. К тому же, хочу заметить что метод [`load`](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) объявлен устаревшим, начиная с версии jQuery 1.8, а в версии 3.0 удален. Да и сама отловка события загрузки изображения имеет ряд проблем.

Comment: load() устаревший ??

Answer (score 2):

Зачем вставлять ссылку для того что бы ее  потом отключать? Можно использовать атрибут `data` для передачи информации.

```js
$(function(){
  $('.small').click(function() {
    var src=$(this).attr('data');
    $('#big img').attr('src', src);
    $('#big img').fadeIn(2000);
  });
});
```

```css
#big img{
  width: 100px;
  display: none;
  }

.small {
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="big"><img src="" alt=""></div>
<p class="small" data="http://www.frut-r.ru/img/90.jpg">img 1</p>
<p class="small" data="http://optominsk.by/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Fruit-and-smoothie.jpg">img 2</p>
<p class="small" data="http://www.giftbaskets.ru/store/images/product/Thinking-of-You-Fruit-Basket-other.jpg">img 3</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

В начало попробуй вставить
`eventObject.stopPropagation();`